Inferring non-linear relationship from rolling correlation between 2 time series
I am reading the paper titled Nowcasting Food Inflation in India: Leveraging Price and Non-Price Signals through Machine Learning  on page 219 of this bulletin: https://rbidocs.rbi.org.in/rdocs/Bulletin/PDFs/0BULT21102024FE151BCBB28594EE4AC96AD2E15451DB0.PDF
Page 223 says:

The relationships between food inflation and some
associated variables have also undergone changes over
time, as reflected in correlation with the variables and
their lags (Chart 2), suggesting the presence of non-
linearities

Chart 2 is on Page 222 of the linked document.
Here is Chart 2:


I have a query. What exactly in the correlation charts is suggestive of non-linearities?
I can see this much : The correlation is changing with time. How does it suggest that there is a non-linear relationship ?

Its interesting because, before I got to your last two lines, I was going to ask you the same question. Once you calculate a moving average of anything, you're generally not expecting a constant  for most economic variables ? So, all I see are not constant plots. But, non-linear ? I have no idea. It's almost as if the author equates non-stationarity with non-linearity ?

How are these curves exactly computed. What do the lag 1 and lag2 refere to? Which two series are the correlations computed for in each of the nine panels?

The relationship between the slope of a linear regression and the correlation is $$b = \rho \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$$
or
$$\rho = b \frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_y}$$
a change in the correlation can be occuring when the slope changes, which may have been the idea behind the claim, but it is not necessarily the case as the example below shows.
In this example we generate data with different levels of noise. The correlation changes if you look at a small window and the slope of a regression line in that place would change as well (regression dilution). But it is not caused by a non-linear relationship, as the relationship is obviously a straight line.

r code to reproduce the figure
set.seed(1)
x = 0:100
y = x+rnorm(101,0,3+10*x/100)

plot(x,y, ylim = c(-30,130))

polygon(10+8*c(-1,1,1,-1,-1),
        10+30*c(-1,-1,1,1,-1), border = 2)

polygon(90+8*c(-1,1,1,-1,-1),
        90+30*c(-1,-1,1,1,-1), border = 2)

text(10,40, round(cor(x[2:18],y[2:18]),3), pos = 3, col = 2)

text(90,120, round(cor(x[82:98],y[82:98]),3), pos = 3, col = 2)

adjusting the code above with
y = 0.01*x^2+rnorm(101,0,3+0*x/100)

you will get

so for for a fixed noise level, a change in correlation would correspond to a change in slope and non-linearity, but as the other example shows, this is not necessarily the case when the noise is heterogeneous.
